# Building IOS Version Using Xcode exported from UNITY3D

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

Dears,

kindly help me figure how to solve an error that occurs when i try to build the exported ios version from unity using Xcode

Also note:
- i have Facebook plugin imported i the project 
- i have googlePLay plugin imported too

the following image represent the error

[image: unity ios error build]
i have ver low experience in IOS so please explain in details if possible (sorry)

thanks in advance every one

Answer (score 0):

Change your "`Target minimum iOS Version`" in Unity Player Settings for iOS from "7.0" to "9.0"

It appears the GooglePlayGames plugin you're using was built for iOS 9.